# Where to authenticate user in a SPA?

Tags: asp.net, authentication, aurelia, auth0

I have an Aurelia SPA that connects to a ASP.NET Core backend. I use Auth0 for authentication (using aurelia-auth, not the Auth0 Lock widget).

I currently log in with Auth0 directly, not using the SPA. This gives me issues because the Auth0 implementation in my API expects the id_token and not the access_token. This issue can be passed by telling aurelia-auth to use the id_token as access token. But this complicates further communication between Auth0 and the Aurelia app. Auth0 expects the access_token for user profile calls and such.

Should I authenticate via my own API instead? Or should I make two different fetch-clients in Aurelia? One for calling my API (using the id_token) and one for calling the Auth0 API (using the access_token).

Answer (score 5):

I've written a number of blogs on the subject, and I'll link them below for further reading. My recommendation is to create a separate "authentication" root viewModel that is available to all users, distinct from your "app" root viewModel which is available to only logged in users.

**main.js**

```
import AuthService from 'AuthService';

export function configure(aurelia) {
    aurelia.use
    .standardConfiguration()
    .developmentLogging();

  // After starting the aurelia, we can request the AuthService directly
  // from the DI container on the aurelia object. We can then set the 
  // correct root by querying the AuthService's isAuthenticated method.
  aurelia.start().then(() => {
        var auth = aurelia.container.get(AuthService);
        let root = auth.isAuthenticated() ? 'app' : 'login';
        aurelia.setRoot(root);
    });
}
```

**Further reading**

- [Aurelia Authentication Best Practices, Multiple Shells](http://davismj.me/blog/aurelia-login-best-practices-pt-1/)
- [Aurelia Authentication Best Practices, Sessions](http://davismj.me/blog/aurelia-auth-pt2/)
- [Sentry, an Aurelia Authentication Template](http://davismj.me/portfolio/sentry/)

Comment: I had already gone the route of two shells. I really like that way of doing it. When it comes to my "real" question I think you missed the mark a bit. I was wondering how to get my own API to work when authenticating the SPA directly with Auth0...
Long story short, I made a new interceptor that uses the id_token as the Bearer and stuff just works :) I removed my extra call to Auth0's api to get the profile because i can ask for it during the login (by asking for "profile" in the scope).
I feel a blogpost brewing.

Comment: Christian did you ever create a blog post on this?  Thanks.